# ¿Cómo proteger la ruta del archivo que realiza la petición Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Entiendo que todo el código que esté al lado del cliente es y será visible, pero al menos no estaría mal hacerlo complicado para los menos expertos en la programación.

Visitar el archivo directo no arrojará ningún mensaje de error.

Pero como puedo proteger la ruta del archivo `var url = "proteger.php";` a lo mejor utilizando `base64_encode` de PHP.

```
$(function() {
var frm = $('#resetform');
frm.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = frm.serialize();
    formData += '&' + $('#submit_btn').attr('name') + '=' + $('#submit_btn').attr('value');
 var url = "proteger.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: url,
        data: formData,
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        let res = JSON.parse(data);
        if(res.status){
            $('#message').fadeIn();
            $('#message').html(res.message).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
            $(frm).hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.href = 'index.php';
    },2000);
  } else {
    $('#message').fadeIn();
    $('#message').html(res.message).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
  }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        $('#message').fadeIn();
        $('#message').html(textStatus).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
    })
});
});
```

Comment: En mi opinión ocultar la URL sirve de muy poco. La seguridad está a otro nivel: generar tokens por ejemplo, dar seguridad al código PHP si accedes a la base de datos, impedir peticiones que vengan de otros dominios, etc. Si `proteger.php` es seguro no tiene ninguna importancia que desde el cliente sepan que ese archivo existe, lo que debes controlar es la forma en que se accede a él o la forma en que se le pide que procese los datos.

Comment: Hola, querés proteger el nombre de la ruta, o sea proteger.php?

Comment: @A.Cedano No sé si estoy confundiendo si es seguro, digo que es seguro porque no genera errores al abrirlo directamente, pero hablando ya de realizar peticiones de otros dominios entonces si puede ser inseguro, puede usted darme un ejemplo de cómo proteger los archivos con usted lo indica con token de seguridad :)

Comment: Fernando lo que pides se aleja del propósito de la pregunta. Hice mi comentario para indicar mejores vías para asegurar tus peticiones Ajax, sabiendo que ofuscar la url sirve de casi nada. Si quieres implementar la seguridad basada en tokens, sugiero que revises [por ejemplo esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31683058/5587982) o algún otro tutorial en la red. No sé si aquí haya ya alguna pregunta que trate sobre el tema.

Comment: hay una falacia en "para los menos expertos en la programación" no son ellos los que deben preocuparte, o tal vez sí: [es muy fácil conseguir un "kit de hacking"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_kiddie) *la versión español de la wiki es medio cualquiera, siempre queda google translate para esos casos. Hace poco hubo una pregunta relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/185206/81450, en cuanto pueda actualizo mi respuesta con varios casos de uso.

Comment: @A.Cedano Excelente el ejemplo enlazado, yo sé que se aleja a la pregunta pero siempre las respuestas se han alejado a lo que se pregunta por los mismos consejos que son muy buenos :)

Comment: @aloMalbarez Tienes razón la preocupación debería darse para lo más expertos. Sí había visto la pregunta pero no llegué a comprender las explicaciones sin embargo la pregunta e respuesta que ha enlazado A.Cedano se ve muy bien la explicación :)

Comment: si, está mas claro en el enlace en inglés, y es lo que falta en la pregunta en español : básicamente (y generalizando un poco) entre páginas usas un token guardado en sesión, entre subdominios hay que modificar la cookie que indica la sesión (en caso de que cada subdominio sea un servidor diferente hay que montar un filesystem compartido), y entre distintos dominios, servidores o lenguajes se usan tokens del tipo hmac (no se guardan en sesión pero son generados a partir de un componente secreto compartido).