# ¿Como ocultar URL en PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html

he visto que muchos tenemos esta duda y recopilando un poco de aqui y de alla llegue a este codigo, pero ya me quede trabajo y tratado de incrustrar el codigo de java pero por mas que lo intento no puedo, ¿pueden ayudarme?

```
$repo=$_POST['imv'];
$t_carp=(int)($repo/100);
$dir = "./repo/".$t_carp."/".$repo."/";
$dh=opendir($dir);
while(!is_bool($file=readdir($dh)))
{
    if(!is_dir("$dir/$file"))
    {
        $filename=($dir.$file);
        echo "<a href='www.google.com' target='myframe2' onclick='<script>javascript:window.location.href('$filename')</script>'>".$file."</a><br/>";
    }
}
closedir($dh);
if (isset($_POST['regresa'])){
    //session_destroy();
    header("Location:RETU_busca.php");
}
```

"myframe" es el nombre del iframe en donde se debe de abrir.

Lo que trato de hacer es generar, por medio de php, links a archivos que estan en el servidor de acuerdo a una eleccion previa del usuario almacenada en $_POST['imv'] pero lo que no quiero es que el usuario común pueda ver el link de los archivos, por lo que, usando javascript trato de enmascarar la dirección que se muestra en la barra de estado.

Comment: Es la pregunta mas confusa que he leido... 1. PHP trabaja desde lado del servidor. 2. Ocultarla de que? o de quien? No especificas bien que es lo que quieres hacer...

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @Pipe lo que trato de hacer es generar por medio de php links a archivos que estan en el servidor de acuerdo a una eleccion previa del usuario almacenada en $_POST['imv'] pero lo que no quiero es que el usuario común pueda ver el link de los archivos, por lo que, usando javascript trato de enmascarar la dirección que se muestra en la barra de estado. ah por cierto, he leido preguntas mas confusas xD, pero bueno ya la clarifique.

Comment: Ok, ahora si mas claro. Volviendo al punto, cual sería la razón para ocultar el link? realmente prácticamente "cualquier" cosa que pasa en el cliente se puede ver, entonces no tiene mucho sentido pelear contra eso. Si lo que quieres es que por ejemplo ese usuario no pueda compartir el link para que otro lo descargue, porque no usas autenticación de usuarios y así puedes generar un link único para cada usuario (y cuyo link solo funciona para esa session)?

Comment: interesante... tienes alguna lectura al respecto? Muchas gracias.

Comment: No, una lectura especifica de eso no tengo... :( y es que son varios temas por aparte que debes unir para lograrlo. Y explicarlo por aqui es laaaaaaargo.
Cual es el objetivo de la "ocultar el link" a ver si depronto te puedo sugerir alguna solución mas simple?

Comment: posiblemente relacionado https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/185206/81450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haz un link que llame a una función javascript. Dentro de esa función puedes poner algo así:

```
function metodo(datos){

    $.ajax({
        url : "codigo.php",
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'text',
        data :  { datos:datos },
        success : function(archivo) {

            var nombreLogico = campo;
            var parametros = "dependent=yes,locationbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,resizable,screenX=50,screenY=50,width=850,height=1050";
            var htmlText = "<embed width=100% height=100% type='application/pdf' src='data:application/pdf,"+escape(archivo)+"'></embed>"; 
            var detailWindow = window.open ("", nombreLogico, parametros);
            detailWindow.document.write(htmlText);
            detailWindow.document.close();
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            alert("error\njqXHR="+jqXHR+"\nstatus="+status+"\nerror="+error);
        },
        complete : function(jqXHR, status) {

        }
    });
}
```

Y dentro de `codigo.php` devuelves el binario del archivo.
De esa forma la url que se ve en el navegador es la de la función y no la del archivo. Yo use este código para mostrar PDFs, si es otro tipo de archivo el manejo de la respuesta debe ser diferente.

Answer (score 0):

investigando sobre el tema, no me dejaba feliz que haya que hacer semejante analisis solo paga ocultar una direccion.

Y encontre un codigo simple en JS que cuando se termina de cargar la pagina, este le cambia la URL.

```
 window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  window.history.replaceState({}, '', 'index')
});
```

Espero sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

De primeras decir que no se si es esto a lo que te refieres. Si no te ayude lo siento, seguramente las respuestas de otros usuarios sean más fáciles o correctas directamente. Pero bueno, yo aquí estoy para aportar mi granito de arena .

En mi caso uso esto, tanto en HTML como en PHP, así que si en algún momento necesitas hacerlo en tu proyecto de HTML, no hay problema.

Y bueno la solución trata de lo siguiente que verás en la captura, y es nombrar la página como index.html y en cambio poner su nombre correcto en la carpeta.

[image: nombres sin extensión]

Por si no lo has entendido del todo, sigue estos pasos:

1. Creas una carpeta con el nombre del archivo (.html o .php), pero sin la extensión, claramente.
2. Luego metes el archivo dentro de la carpeta con su mismo nombre.
3. Por último, pero no menos importante, renombras el archivo con index.html o index.php, dependiendo del lenguaje que estés usando.

Ahora cuando hagas una redirección a este archivo en vez de poner la ruta completa, simplemente pon la ruta hasta la carpeta y por tanto no se mostrara la ruta con el archivo, es decir en vez de: "tuurl/prueba1/prueba1.html", se mostrará "tuurl/prueba1/"

¡Un saludo. Espero que te haya ayudado y suerte en tu proyecto!

Comment: Si no sabés a qué se refiere el OP, debés dejar un comentario en la pregunta, (cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](/help/privileges)). La zona de respuestas es para respuestas _completas_ a la pregunta.